# How to get a version of sonarqube for use with JDK6

Tags: java, installation, sonarqube, jdk6

I need to get a version of Sonarqube ( or Sonar ) that works with Java 6, but I can´t find to download.
Someone can indicate where I can find it ? 
I´ve searched on Sonarqube site, but nothing.

PS: It´s because my company still using Java 6. A migration for Java 7 ( yes! I know this version is in end of life too! ) is in study, but not started yet.

Thanks !
Alexandre

Comment: Why do you think that Sonarcube has problems  with Java6?

Comment: @AlexWien Because on Sonarqube donwload page the versions are 5.1.1 and 4.5.4 . The page http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+4.5+Upgrade+Notes  says **"JRE / JDK 6 is no longer supported to run SonarQube starting from 4.5.1"**

Comment: You don't need to use Java 6 for running SonarQube. Your source code and SonarQube can use different Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SonarQube 4.5.x, Java 7 is required to run the server and analysis code.

You will still be able to analyze Java 6 code, but if you want to run with an older JDK, you will be restricted to older versions (of both server and analysis plugins).